# Unable to use same clientId on 3 HA cluster architecture

Tags: activemq-artemis, webmethods

I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis cluster of 3 brokers (1 master, 2 slaves), setup with UDP broadcast.

ActiveMQ Artemis is starting as expected, but when trying create JMS connections using SAG webMethods it returns the error:

```
clientID=activemq was already set into another connection
```

I have 3 Integration servers, each configured with this JNDI config, pointing to 3 ActiveMQ Artemis brokers:

- **Initial Context Factory**: `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory`
- **Provider URL**: `tcp://S1:9000?sslEnabled=true&ha=true&reconnectAttempts=-1`
- **Provider URL Failover List**: `tcp://S2:9000?sslEnabled=true,tcp://S3:9000?sslEnabled=true`

I need to connect my T1, T2 and T3 webmethods servers to the ActiveMQ Artemis cluster. On T1 server, I manage to establish JMS connection with `activemq` as clientID. But on remaining T2 and T3 webmethods servers, the error `clientID=activemq was already set into another connection` is returned.

ActiveMQ Artemis supports JMS 2.0 and multiple clients pointing to same clientID/destination should be possible right? It allows shared subscription.

What I'm missing here? I do not created any topic at all, I only want to establish the JMS connections on 3 servers first.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ Artemis does support JMS 2.0 and therefore shared durable subscriptions, but section 6.1.2 of the JMS 2 specification states:

> The purpose of client identifier is to associate a connection and its objects
>   with a state maintained on behalf of the client by a provider. **By definition,
>   the client state identified by a client identifier can be ‘in use’ by only one
>   client at a time.** A JMS provider must prevent concurrently executing
>   clients from using it.
>
> ...
>
> The only use of a client identifier defined by JMS is its mandatory use in
>   identifying an unshared durable subscription or its **optional** use in
>   identifying a shared durable or non-durable subscription. [emphasis mine]

Therefore, the reason you're getting the exception is because you're attempting to violate the JMS specification. Please set a unique client identifier for each durable subscriber or simply omit the client identifier if you're using a shared durable subscription.

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for your response.
I'm using a shared durable subscriber, I want the events to be processed once by 1 of the 3 nodes.
If I only provide the clientId at 1/3 JMS connections, the trigger using this destination does not start at the connections without clientId:
Cannot create durable subscription - client ID has not been set

Is it possible to define clientId on connection factory, reusing clientID on the 3 JMS connections? I need the 3 connections listening

If so, do you know where I need to change? On the JNDI provider URL? Broker.xml? artemis.profile?

Thank you!

Comment: What API call are you using to create the shared durable subscription? As noted in my answer, the client ID is mandatory for an unshared durable subscription but *optional* for a shared durable subscription. It sounds like you're using an API call which is creating an unshared durable subscription.

Comment: It's the webmethods integration server that using the API behind the scenes...and we are suspecting they use it the same way as on their internal messaging component, and therefore calling a wrong API that does not fully support JMS 2.0. The only way to check is decompiling the product libs....

Comment: If the application isn't calling the proper JMS 2.0 method then you won't be able to share a subscription among multiple consumers. That feature is only supported in JMS 2.0. For what it's worth, this is another good reason to use Open Source software - you can just look and see exactly what it's doing.